# Python How to use an OrderdDict like a Linked List to insert in the middle in constant time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

An OrderedDict maintains order with a doubly-linked list implementation.

How can I use an OrderedDict like a Linked List, in order to insert into the middle of a list in constant time?

For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

o = OrderedDict
# ...

for node in o:
    if some_condition(node):
        node.add({'k': 'v'})
        break
```

Comment: I don't think OrderedDict supports that. If you want constant insert time in the middle of a list, you'd probably have to implement a single/doubly linked list with each element being a tuple or a dict your self. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154946/python-linked-list-o1-insert-remove)

Comment: @blueishpoop I was hoping to find a C-implemented built in module to handle inserting into the middle of a list in constant time.

Comment: So I was doing some googling and found [this extension module](https://pypi.org/project/llist/) with [documentation](https://ajakubek.github.io/python-llist/index.html). Hopefully it helps with whatever you need.